# Merging pandas categorical Series with renaming

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, categorical-data

I am looking for a way to merge categories of one object of `pandas.Series` to categories of another.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, Categorical

N = Series(["a","b","c","a"], dtype="category", name = "NEW_TEST")
N1 = N.copy()
N2 = N.copy()
```

**Works**

```
N1.cat.categories = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC']
```

**Throws error** `ValueError: Categorical categories must be unique`

```
N2.cat.categories = ['AA', 'AA', 'CC']
```

I would like to rename-merge categories. Thus all values from category `b` will end-up in category `AA`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing this is just to assign the category to all elements in the series of the category you want to rename:

```
In [59]: N
Out[59]:
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
Name: NEW_TEST, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [a < b < c]

In [60]: N[N=='b'] = 'a'

In [61]: N
Out[61]:
0    a
1    a
2    c
3    a
Name: NEW_TEST, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [a < b < c]
```

Now, all elements with category 'b' are assigned with category 'a'. If you now remove category 'b', this will end up with a 'merge' in practice:

```
In [62]: N.cat.remove_unused_categories()
Out[62]:
0    a
1    a
2    c
3    a
dtype: category
Categories (2, object): [a < c]

In [63]: N.cat.remove_categories(['b'])
Out[63]:
0    a
1    a
2    c
3    a
dtype: category
Categories (2, object): [a < c]
```

Comment: might want to mention ``.rename_categories`` as well

Comment: @Jeff How can you do it with rename? As `.rename_categories(['a', 'a', 'c'])` does raise that they should be unique

Comment: In [25]: N.cat.rename_categories(['A','B','C'])
Out[25]: 
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    A
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [A < B < C]

Comment: but that's just straight renaming. I guess you are not doing that here.

Comment: yes, indeed, it is renaming to one of the other categories